# How to initialize a pre-formatted datepicker in jQuery-UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm applying a datepicker to a form field with this date format: `'dd/mm/yy'` so when the user selects a date it will be placed in that format in the field.

The problem is that field is pre-filled with a value in format `yy-mm-dd`, and the datepicker is showing the today date.

How can I initialize the datepicker with the field value?

I have previously used the datepicker from jQuery Tools, that automatically initializes the datepicker from the field value, but the one from jQuery UI does not have that useful functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it is:

```
$('#activity_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' })
$('#activity_date').datepicker("setDate", "2012-01-21")
$('#activity_date').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy")
```

Explanation:

- set the dateFormat like the one in the database
- set the date
- set the dateFormat that we want to show in the form field

Comment: Doesn't seem to format the date if the field has a default value